# Empty value in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store the value by clicking on an image, however, Once I click onsubmit to send the post over to firestore it doesn't have the value from the image clicked.

[image]

Can you please help me?

I want to click on the image and the value of the image must be store in firestore

Feeling: Sad, neutral, happy (this is what I want to have)

```
import { addDoc, collection} from "@firebase/firestore";
import { db, auth } from '../../services/authService';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyModal({ isOpen, onClose }) {

    const [postText, setPostText] = useState("");
    const [feeling, setFeeling] = useState("")

    const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleAdd = async () => {
    
            await addDoc(postsCollectionRef, {
                feeling,
                postText,
                date: String(new Date()), 
                author: { name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid },
            }).then(() => {
                alert("publicación subida");
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
              });
                navigate("/home");}
                
           
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
        
    }
```

```
return (
        <Container>
            <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleAdd}>
                <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                    <DialogTitle>How are you feeling today?</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            <Button
                            value="Good"
                            onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component="img"
                                    height="50"
                                    image={Good}
                                    alt="Feeling awesome"
                                    value={feeling}
                                />
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                            value="Neutral"
                            onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component="img"
                                    height="50"
                                    image={Neutral}
                                    alt="Feeling Neutral"
                                />
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                            value="Bad"
                            onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component="img"
                                    height="50"
                                    image={Bad}
                                    alt="Feeling Bad"
                                />
                            </Button>
                        </DialogContentText>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        <DialogTitle>Type how are you feeling today...</DialogTitle>
                    </DialogContentText>
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            marginLeft: '20px',
                            width: 300,
                            maxWidth: '100%',
                        }}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth label="Type here your answer"
                            id="fullWidth"
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                setPostText(event.target.value);
                            }}
                            style={{
                                marginBottom: "10%"
                            
                            }} />
                    </Box>

                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                marginLeft: '20px',
                                width: 300,
                                maxWidth: '100%',
                            }}
                        >
                        </Box>
                        
                    </LocalizationProvider>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={onClose} color="secondary">
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button type="submit" onClick={handleAdd} color="primary">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default MyModal
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons are tied to this handler:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    
}
```

Since you call `e.preventDefault()`, you suppress the default behavior of the button - so your `handleAdd` never will get called.

You'll also want to double-check if your `Button` class actually submits the form to begin with, as that might require them to have `type="submit"`.

---

Even if your `onSubmit` *does* get called, nothing in that code currently knows what button the user clicked. So unless you want to switch over to using a radio group for the inputs, you're probably better off handling the write in `onSubmit` and removing the need for a form-level submit handler altogether.